# How do I add an UPDATE CASCADE to a Rails-Postgres migration?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-keys, rails-migrations

I need to write a Rails migration that will update the uuid of a specific object and then CASCADE through all the rows storing that id as a foreign key, like so:

```
alter table projects add constraint fk_league
foreign key (user_id) references users(id) on update cascade
```

Unfortunately Rails appears to auto-generate the constraint:

```
fk_rails_e4348431a9
```

How would I write the above sql to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presumably you have a `t.references` or `t.belongs_to` somewhere in your migrations:

```
t.references :user, :foreign_key => true
```

The `t.references` is just an [`add_reference`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) call in disguise. The `add_reference` documentation doesn't say anything useful about the value for the `:foreign_key` option but [the code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L653) does:

```
foreign_key_options = options.delete(:foreign_key)
#...
if foreign_key_options
  to_table = Base.pluralize_table_names ? ref_name.to_s.pluralize : ref_name
  add_foreign_key(table_name, to_table, foreign_key_options.is_a?(Hash) ? foreign_key_options : {})
end
```

So when you specify the `:foreign_key` option, you can hand it a Hash of options for the underlying [`add_foreign_key`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key) call and that has an `:on_update` option:

> `:on_update`
>   Action that happens `ON UPDATE`. Valid values are `:nullify`, `:cascade:` [sic] and `:restrict`

You'd want to replace your original `t.references` call with something more like this:

```
t.references :user, :foreign_key => { :on_update => :cascade }
```

---

If you already have everything set up on production and you need to alter the FK constraint, then I think you'd need to fix things up by hand:

1. Add a migration to drop the original constraint and add the updated one:

   ```
   def up
     connection.execute(%q{
       alter table projects
       drop constraint fk_rails_e4348431a9
     })
     connection.execute(%q{
       alter table projects
       add constraint fk_rails_e4348431a9
       foreign key (user_id)
       references users(id)
       on update cascade
     })
   end
   def down
     # The opposite of the above...
   end
   ```

   You probably don't need to keep the constraint name that Rails chose but you might as well.
2. Manually edit your `db/schema.rb` to add the above `:foreign_key => { :on_update => :cascade }` to the appropriate `t.references` call.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was a way to specify it only on the table where I was updating the primary key, then have the update auto cascade, but I will have to do it the hard way. This should work.